# vue bootstrap datetimepicker no muestra iconos

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

bootstrap-datetimepicker en un componente vue. Pero el problema que tengo es que no se muestran los iconos del calendario. En la documentación dice que tengo que importarlos con jquery. pero al hacerlo, me sigue sin mostrar los iconos. Alguien podria ayudarme?

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.use(datePicker)

jQuery.extend(true, jQuery.fn.datetimepicker.defaults, {
  icons: {
    time: 'far fa-clock',
    date: 'far fa-calendar',
    up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
    down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
    today: 'fas fa-calendar-check',
    clear: 'far fa-trash-alt',
    close: 'far fa-times-circle'
  }
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

componente.js

```
<template>
<date-picker v-model="form.dateInit" :config="form.optionsDateInit"></date-picker>
</template>
```

Comment: VueJS y jQuery no deberían utilizarse juntos.

Comment: ¿Todos los iconos o sólo las flechas?

Comment: @milmal Todos los iconos